# Bind events to loaded canvas objects

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Currently I'm loading canvas objects with the `loadFromJSON(json)` method. I use it to implement an undo function for the canvas.

Before I restore a canvas state, each canvas object has a mouse event bound. Is there any possibility to save the event when serializing?

At this moment I solve this problem by using the `reviveropt` callback in the `loadFromJSON` method. To bind the correct event callback function, I need the index of the currently loaded object on the canvas. How can I acquire this?

**EDIT**
Below I added code to make my clarify question.

After the user clicks Undo, I pop the latest `history` object from the `history`-array. Afterwards I call:

`this.canvas.loadFromJSON(canvasJSON, this.rerenderAll.bind(this), function(object){ this._loadSeatEvents(object);}.bind(this));`, where canvasJSON is the serialized canvas and `this._loadSeatEvents(object)` is the `reviveropt`.

Within the `reviveropt` I have to bind an event depending on the index on the canvas. For example: the first 5 (calculated @runtime) objects should have `handlerA`bound, the next 9 (again calculated @runtime) objects should have `handlerB` bound, etc.

Comment: For the index, I believe that the reviveropt will go through the objects on the canvas in order of their z-index.  The object at the back goes first and so on.  You could declare an index before using the loadFromJSON and then increment it on every pass.  Realistically, I'm not 100% I understand your problem; could you post a jsFiddle or more code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added some code to clarify the question. The use of an index could indeed work, but isn't there an OOTB method provided? Won't an index slow down the recreation of the canvas?

Comment: I'm not aware of an OOTB method and I don't think an index is going to have any noticeable performance concerns.